# NewtonSoft: Extract same attribute from An Array of objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I receive the following JSON from a web API.

```
{"total_rows":5,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"a:d1","key":"a:d1","value":{"rev":"1-d8e292f1d70505a11be43effaade798b"}},
{"id":"a:d2","key":"a:d2","value":{"rev":"1-a6d5df7769b00e147a3be2a564ffb0e4"}},
{"id":"a:d3","key":"a:d3","value":{"rev":"1-a90506b1445931825a09e7ef5658bc1a"}},
{"id":"b:d4","key":"b:d4","value":{"rev":"1-803b2ff44fe97407a918c6cabc294822"}},
{"id":"b:d5","key":"b:d5","value":{"rev":"1-7e305ced65c3c36070d1adf1bbe1b2ff"}}
]}
```

I need to read all the "id" values and load them in a string array in C#.
Essentially giving me a string array such as

```
["a:d1"]
["a:d2"]
["a:d3"]
["b:d4"]
["b:d5"]
```

However i cant deserialize the JSON into an known object class as the structure of JSON may change, but presence of "rows" & "id" is guaranteed.

I am new to JSON and C# and any help would be much appreciated.

Thanking you in advance for your time and effort.

Comment: *"the structure of JSON may change"* - Will there always be a `rows` property containing the data you want?

Comment: Yes. The rows property and "id" property will ALWAYS be present. What can change is the properties/attributes within a row.

Comment: You could parse it into an object with total_rows, offset, and a dictionary for the rows. That way, you can ignore all other fields besides "id" and just retrieve the id from a row using the key value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the structure of JSON may change, but presence of "rows" & "id" is guaranteed

Then the structure you care about doesn't change.  Just define your classes for that structure:

```
public class MyRow
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public IEnumerable<MyRow> rows { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize into that object:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json);
```

Then you can map your rows to the array:

```
var result = obj.rows.Select(r => r.id);
```

Comment: David - thank you for your quick response. This works. Kindly indulge my curiosity, can the same be achieved WITHOUT deserializing? With JSON.Parse ?

Comment: @user15360876: Do you mean `JObject.Parse`?  I would imagine so.  As long as the input is valid JSON and as long as the properties you're looking for exist, there's nothing stopping you from getting those properties.

Comment: I already tried something like

JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(MyJSON);
JArray ids = (JArray)jobj["rows"]["id"];
string[] sIds = ids.Select(c => (string)c).ToArray();

but the ids would always be null.
Maybe i am missing something obvious.

Comment: @user15360876: I haven't used `JObject`, but this notation looks suspect: `jobj["rows"]["id"]`  The `rows` property is an array.  An array doesn't have a property called `id`.  You need to iterate through the rows and get the `id` from each element.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all id from rows with [`SelectTokens`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm)

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var result = jObject.SelectTokens("rows[*].id").Select(w => w.ToString()).ToArray();
// result => ["a:d1","a:d2","a:d3","b:d4","b:d5"]
```